# Toolbar>>#commandSource in Dolphin Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, dolphin-smalltalk

I want to create a reusable toolbar that handles its own commands. Unfortunately, Toolbar overrides #commandSource to treat the topShell as the commandSource. I'd like to have the parentView be the commandSource instead. To do this I've created a subclass of Toolbar and provided my own method override. Is there another way to do this? It seems odd that Toolbar is such an outlier in bypassing the command chain.